# Adobe Acrobat X Pro - Exportar PDF para texto acessível

Tags: c#, pdf

estou em um projeto lendo PDF através de C# 2012 com ASPOSE. Porém estou com dificuldades de ler paginas que possuam varias colunas.

Por exemplo: um pdf pode ter na pagina 1 (um) duas colunas e na pagina 3 (três) 5 colunas e na sexta pagina em diante ter apenas 1 (uma) coluna.

Não tenho como saber previamente em que pagina sairão e em quantas colunas.

Pensei em usa o SDK do ADOBE ACROBAT X PRO para exportar em .txt acessível (com marcador de quebra de pagina), mas não sei se é a melhor solução.

Utilizando o SAVE AS (nao via sdk) do Acrobat percebi que não exporta corretamente, será que estou fazendo algo errado?

Qual pode me orientar?

PS: já utilizei inicalmente iTextSharp, porem o Aspose se mostrou uma ferramenta extremamente melhor que o aspose.

Desde já agradeço,
Marco Araujo

Comment: De uma olhada no [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/)

Comment: Baixei e testei o programa. Ótimo resultado de conversão. Existe um SDK para eu incorporar na minha aplicação? Pesquisei na web mas nao encontrei nada de SDK deste PDFMATE.

Comment: Desconheço, sei que da para adicionar no Visual Studio pelo nuget as dll, mas fora isso, acho que não tem `SDK`.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Você conhece algum bom conversor de PDF para texto que possua SDK?

Comment: Tem o Foxit, mas é pago...